# Schwarz reflection over $S(0,1)$

Tags: complex-analysis

My homework problem is to explain in short conditions that a function $f$ should satisfy so we can aply Schwarz reflection over $S(0,1)$. I understand this principle for reflection over a line, but for sphere I don't.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: Use preimages of the exponential $\exp \colon ℂ → ℂ^×$ to think about reflections at the circle.

Comment: If I understood well, you mean to use the fact that preimage of unit sphere for $exp$ is boundary of rectangle and then try to reflect over that lines?

Comment: @user101521 Kind of. The preimage of the unit circle under $\exp$ is $iℝ$ (not a rectangle, you probably were thinking of the preimage of the unit *disk*). For $f\colon D → ℂ$, you can check $f ∘ \exp$ on $f^{-1}(D)$ for the conditions of the Schwarz reflections principle. You just need to figure out what you can do with this.

Comment: So, I'm checking $f\circ exp$ on $f^{-1}(D)$ for reflextion over imaginary axis?

Comment: @user101521 Yeah, that’s the idea. Well, it sounds like you need to figure out a formal statement for the reflection principle for the circle and then prove it. For this, you can proceed like you said.

Comment: Does this mean that $f$ must be biholomorphic and $D \subset f(D)$?